# Aws ecs service isn't updating new task definations

Tags: aws-ecs

I have created new ecs cluster with 2 container instances and running 2 tasks, whenever i update new task defination in service, service is not replacing existing task and it's trying to create new task and i am getting error events like no enough cpu and mem , my question is  why ecs service is trying to create new task without stopping existing tasks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 2 hrs of research found solution, min and max health check percentage in service causing the issue